# How to configure URL of a WCF Service referenced within another WCF Service Library

Tags: c#, wcf

This is hard to explain so please ask me to clarify anything that is unclear.

I have 3 WCF web service libraries and 3 host applications I will call them `Service1`, `Service2` and `Service3`.  Service2 is in the same solution but is not relevant to this question at the moment.

`Service1` references `Service3` Host Application. Once it is compiled I cannot see any way to configure the URL  for `Service3` in `Service1`.

I would like it to be in the config for `Service1` Host Application.  Is this possible?  I can't believe this is hard coded in the DLL?

Service1 Library App.Config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Service3Data" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://MyHost/gws/GService3.svc/gwd"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service3Data"
    contract="GServices3.IGws" name="Service3Data" />
</client>
<services>
  <service name="MyNameSpace.Business.WebServices.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyNameSpace.Business.WebServices.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyNameSpace.Business.WebServices/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Service1 Host Application Web.Config (and where I need to configure the URL for Service3):

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Service1Binding" openTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646"
      maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
        maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyNameSpace.Business.WebServices.Service1">
    <endpoint address="bwd" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service1Binding"
      name="BWData" contract="MyNameSpace.Business.WebServices.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: When you say "Service1 references Service3 Host Application", do you mean you create a proxy for Service3 in Service1?

Comment: @Szymon Sorry, yes that is what I mean.

Comment: OK, so adding a proxy means that you should have an entry in Service1's config file as well and you should be able to set the URL in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a proxy for a WCF service, you can always add a `<system.serviceModel>` section to the main assembly and configure all the settings in there (including the URL of the service you creates a proxy for).

If you add your proxy in a library assembly, you can still add `<system.serviceModel>` to the main (executable/web host/etc.) assembly.

You need to copy the `<client>` section from the library config to the host application config (together with its binding and possibly other elements).

Comment: So you are saying I can just add the proxy for Service3 in the Web.Config for Service1 Host Application?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can always add config for the proxy, even if you generate it somewhere else (in another assembly). The config will be automatically used. I updated my answer.